# Can postscript programmatically create and name pages?

Tags: postscript

In PostScript, pages typically take the form of

```
%%Pages: 2
...
%%Page: (My First Page) 1
...
showpage
%%Page: (My Second Page) 2
...
showpage
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to create pages -- including labeling and numbering them -- with commands. For example, can you create a function that creates a page each time it is called? I realize you could call `showpage`, but that doesn't give you very good results.

Comment: It is not stricto sensu Postscript, but the [DSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Structuring_Conventions). A PostScript file could have no comments at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't give you very good results"?

Comment: showpage doesn't produce new pages, at least not in GhostScript, unless you have both a %%Pages: comment at the top and a %%Page: comment before each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct standards involved here. One is the PostScript language, which only cares about the `showpage` calls and ignores all lines beginning with `%`. This includes the magic line `%!` or `%!PS-Adobe-1.0` or whatever. The postscript don't care!

The other standard is the Document Structuring Conventions which dictates the layout of the `%%Page:` comments and the strict separation of the prep code from the code for the pages with one or more `%%Prolog` sections. The version number in the magic line actually identifies the DSC version, not the PS level. `%!PS-Adobe-2.0` is DSC version 2.0.

But as mentioned in the comments, it's perfectly possible to write postscript with no comments. Thus it's possible to write without DSC comments. In order to *flatten* the code out (unroll the loops, etc) and add DSC comments, you can use ghostscript's ps2write device (`-sDEVICE=ps2write`), or check the old [still.ps](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/F4tFfdmGkZY/discussion) which generates the document to stdout.